# Compressing Directory

Tags: shell-script, shell

I want to compress (`tar` or `gzip` or `zip`) directories older than two days. I have the files below. Each directory will have multiple subdirectories and files.

```
Oct 21 13:01 test1
Oct 22 13:01 test2
```

Desired output:

```
   test1.tar
   test2.tar
```

I tried writing the command, below; but, it is not working.

```
   find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mtime +2 \! -name '*.gz' -exec gzip {} \;
```

I am getting the below error.

```
   gzip:test1.tar is a directory -- ignored
   gzip:test2.tar is a directory -- ignored
```

Comment: Like the man said : gzip, gunzip, zcat - compress or expand **files**

Comment: I tried running this script but it is not working..what is wrong with      
j=`find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime -2`
echo "$j"
for i in "$j"
do
[ -d "$i" ] && zip -r "$i.zip" "$i"
done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because gzip can ONLY compress files, you first must tar the directories prior to gzipping them.

What you want to do is use GNU `tar` with "z", "z" compresses:

`find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mtime +2 \! -name '*.gz' -exec tar cfz {}.tgz {} \;`

EDIT After Comment:

I had not paid attention to `\! -name '*.gz'`, which under normal circumstances is superfluous ... provided you have no directory names ending in `.gz`.

`find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mtime +2 -exec tar cfz {}.tgz {} \;`

Comment: I will try this

Comment: @Naresh: I would add `-mindepth 1` to avoid packing `.`. `\! -name '*.gz'` is redundant since you filter for directories - unless you have and want to ignore directories name `*.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`tar`** archiving utility:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mtime +2 ! -name '*.gz' -exec tar -czvf old_dirs.gz '{}' +;
```

---

> **`-exec command {} +`** 
>                 This  variant of the `-exec` action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built
>                 by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be **much less**
>                 than  the  number of matched files.

Comment: Nice example for `+`, however, op wanted `test1.tar` and `test2.tar`, not `all_dirs.gz`.